# Reading a named calendar's events

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I am trying to write a script that deletes all the events from every calendar in a certain month. Based on [this method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#getEvents(Date,Date)) it looks like I am using the correct code, but every time I try to run this code, I get the error,

> TypeError: Cannot find function getEvents in object Calendar. (line 17, file "Code")

My code is:

```
function myFunction() {  
  var year = 2018;
  var month = 11;

  var fromDate = new Date(year,month,1,0,0,0);
  var toDate = new Date(year,month,28,0,0,0);

  var calendars = ['def', 'Appointments', 'Chores', 'Contacts', 'Dates', 'Errand', 'IMPORTANT!!', 'Scheduling','Time-Sensitive', 'TV Show', 'Work'];

  for (var x = 0; x < calendars.length; x++) {  
    var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName(calendars[x])[0];
    var events = calendar.getEvents(fromDate, toDate);

    for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
      var ev = events[i];
      ev.deleteEvent();
    }
  }
}
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I would use getCalendarByID.

Comment: If you know for a fact that there is only one calendar with each name then you can add [0] to calendar and I think that might work.

Comment: You're treating an [array of calendars](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-app#getcalendarsbynamename) as if they are a single one...

Comment: @Cooper I do know for a fact that each calendar has a unique name so I tried adding '[0]' but I got a typeerror.
Change:   var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName(calendars[x][0]);
TypeError: Cannot find function getEvents in object . (line 17, file "Code")

is .getEvents() not a defined function?

Comment: It works for me.  So do you have the Calendar API enabled.  You will have to enable it in the script editor and the [developers console](https://console.cloud.google.com/project/707298365023/apiui/api).

Comment: hmm I enabled it in the script editor (when it asked for permissions) but when in the developer's console, the 'Enable' button is grayed out and when I hover over the button it says "You do not have permission to enable this service'.  Why can't I use that service?

Comment: Is the code in this question the only code in your script project (not just script file, the whole project)? If not, when it is, does it work as intended? If so, you have interfering code defined elsewhere.

Comment: It is the only code I wrote.  Do I need to make a new project? If so, how?

Comment: Are you certain you are providing the correct names? Compare the names you are providing here with the actual names that are logged by `CalendarApp.getAllCalendars().forEach(function (cal) { Logger.log(cal.getName()) })`

Comment: @tehhowch that function is very helpful, anyway I ran it and yes all the calendars have the correct names but I am still getting the error `TypeError: Cannot call method "getEvents" of undefined. (line 13, file "Code")` pointing to the first line that has `getEvents()`.

Comment: Your comment has a different error message than your post-which is it? Additionally, where are your debugging logs? For example, what is `x` when the error appears? Does this issue persist when you `.filter` the result of `getAllCalendars` by the desired name?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName(calendars[x]);` returns an array.  To access even the first and only element in the array you can do this:
`var calendar=CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName(calendars[x])[0];` so that now the variable calendar is now a calendar and not an array of calendars.

Here's the form the script script I'm using:

```
function myFunction101() {  
  var year=2018;
  var month=11;
  var fromDate=new Date(year,month,1,0,0,0);
  var toDate=new Date(year,month,28,0,0,0);
  var calendars=['', ''];//using my calendars
  for(var x=0;x<calendars.length;x++) {
    var calendar=CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName(calendars[x])[0];
    var events=calendar.getEvents(fromDate, toDate);
    for(var i = 0; i < events.length; i++){
      var ev = events[i];
      Logger.log(ev.getTitle());
      //ev.deleteEvent();
    }

  }

}
```

Comment: Your reasoning sounds right and I changed my code to `var calendar=CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName(calendars[x])[0];` but I am still getting the `TypeError: Cannot find function getEvents in object . (line 17, file "Code")`

Comment: Please update the code in your question so I can see what you have.

Comment: ok, I updated my code above.  When run it gives the TypeError from my previous comment.

Comment: It's working for me. So did you enable the Calendar API in your script editor and at the [Cloud Platform API Dashboard](https://console.cloud.google.com/project/707298365023/apiui/api)?

Comment: affirmative sir