# google-apps-script | Delete all events in a month

Tags: google-apps-script

I am writing a script to delete every event from each of my calendars in a single month.  My code:

```
function myFunction() {  
var year = 2018;
var month = 11;

var fromDate = new Date(year,month,1,0,0,0);
var toDate = new Date(year,month,28,0,0,0);

var calendars = ['cal1', 'cal2', 'cal3','cal4','cal5','cal6'];

 for (var x = 0; x < calendars.length; x++) {

  var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName(calendars[x])[0];
  var events = calendar.getEvents(fromDate, toDate);

  for(var i = 0; i < events.length; i++){
    var ev = events[i];
    ev.deleteEvent();
  }

}

}
```

When I run my code I get the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot call method "getEvents" of undefined. (line 13, file
>   "Code")

Am I not running getEvents() on a calendar object?  Why is this code give me an error when it tries to use that function?

Comment: Why are you re asking? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54852797/reading-a-named-calendars-events

Comment: I thought that guy was just stumped and finished... should I give that one more time?

Comment: No. You failed to update the error you receive when you changed the code. The issue is trivial now; follow my tip there and you'll figure it out

Comment: I did update the code there and ran your function (which I found very useful to know for future use) but I am still having a problem.  I moved back to the original question for posting.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

I removed the deleteEvents because I don't want to delete my events.  But this code produced Calendar Name, Event Title, Event StartTime and Event EndTime for all event in the given period.

```
function myFunction() {  
  var year = 2018;
  var month = 11;  
  var fromDate = new Date(year,month,1,0,0,0);
  var toDate = new Date(year,month,28,0,0,0);
  var calendars = ['You'll have to put your calendar names back in here.']
  var html='';
  for (var x=0;x<calendars.length;x++) {
    var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName(calendars[x]);
    var events = calendar[0].getEvents(fromDate, toDate);
    for(var i = 0; i < events.length; i++){
      var ev = events[i];
      html+=Utilities.formatString('<br />Calendar Name: %s<br />EventTitle: %s<br />EventStartTime: %s<br />Event End Time: %s',calendar[0].getName(),events[i].getTitle(),events[i].getStartTime(),events[i].getEndTime() );
    } 
  } 
  var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(userInterface, 'Calendar Events')
}
```